# Spring integration pass ImmutableCollection in payload

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have scenario in which channel is triggered from gateway and ImutableList is passed to further SI chain. But the step of triggering SI chain from gateway is failing. Further investigating on the error cause I was able to find out the failure was because SI was trying to convert source object in target type(in my case the return type of source and argument for target method is same). For my case it was first creating empty collection using default constructor and then call addAll method to insert all elements in the target type.

Gateway

```
 <gateway id="fooService"
     service-interface="org.example.FooService"
     default-request-channel="requestChannel"
     default-reply-channel="nullChannel"
     error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<chain input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="nullChannel">
      <service-activator ref=DummyClass" method="dummyMethod" />
</chain>
```

Code snippet where conversion takes place

```
public static Collection createCollection(Class<?> collectionType, int initialCapacity) {
if (collectionType.isInterface()) {
    if (List.class.equals(collectionType)) {
        return new ArrayList(initialCapacity);
    }
    else if (SortedSet.class.equals(collectionType) || collectionType.equals(navigableSetClass)) {
        return new TreeSet();
    }
    else if (Set.class.equals(collectionType) || Collection.class.equals(collectionType)) {
        return new LinkedHashSet(initialCapacity);
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Collection interface: " + collectionType.getName());
    }
}
else {
    if (!Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(collectionType)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported Collection type: " + collectionType.getName());
    }
    try {
        // Step where code fails. As immutable implementation will never have a default constructor.
        return (Collection) collectionType.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not instantiate Collection type: " +
                collectionType.getName(), ex);
    }
}}
```

[Source link](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.core/3.2.5/org/springframework/core/CollectionFactory.java#CollectionFactory.createCollection%28java.lang.Class%2Cint%29)

I did fixed it temporarily by using a List but was thinking ImmutableCollection should be supported. How can i use ImmutableCollections in this case.

**Update**-20160126

**[Sample Git Link](https://github.com/meherzad/SITest)**
   I have created both success and failure case.

Just changing the target type to any mutable collection like List was required.

Comment: OK. Would you mind to share the code to test/confirm that it looks like a bug?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for the response. I was able to quickly create a sample with success and failure case. I have added details to the question.

Comment: OK, Thank you! BTW we don't need the gateway bridge there to play. There is just enough to send your payload to the channel where your service-activator is seating.

Comment: Yeah. i was just making the sample simple of what im actually trying in my project where i have error handling and multiple channels for redirection. Also i prefer way of creating the gateway object to forward the message to required channel.

Comment: Yeah. I see. From other side, please, explain the reason to deal with target types, but not their interfaces, like `List` in your case? See `CollectionToCollectionConverter` from where the cause is coming. We return the `source` anyway, because of `boolean copyRequired = !targetType.getType().isInstance(source);`. No need to worry about the `target`, because it will be exactly the same `source`.

Comment: Yeah i understand. After debugging i was able to see source is coming up as RegularImmutableList instead of ImmutableList which is causing issue further on. I dont know why the source type is changing.

Comment: I got it :) ImmutableList is abstract class and the static method of() which im using return the concrete implementation of ImmutableList which is RegularImmutableList. grep code link -> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/19.0-rc1/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#ImmutableList.asImmutableList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Integration POJO method in vocation is based on the `ConversionService` to allow do not care about the `source` objects and just try to coerce them to our `target` type.

In case of `ImmutableList` we end up with the issue that we can't instantiate the class because it isn't interface and is `abstract` class.

From one side it would be better to rely on the contracts and accept in the method arguments interfaces, assuming that any `Collection` impl will be passed as is without conversion. If the items are in the expected item type, of course, otherwise the `CollectionToCollectionConverter` does the stuff. That's why we need interfaces to allow `CollectionFactory.createCollection()` instantiate the target collection properly.

You even can fully bypass conversion if your service will accept `Message<?>` instead of `payload` type, e.g.:

```
public static class ImmutableListService {

    public void handle(Message<ImmutableList<String>> data) {
        System.out.println("!!!!" + data);
    }

}
```

There is nothing to do from the Framework perspective, but sorry for the inconvenience. Not sure how to help else, but you'd not receive the issue, if the contract would be based on the interfaces.